# Standalone Tomcat protection against rogue domains pointing to its IP

Tags: tomcat, redirect, dns

Anyone who has a domain name can choose to point it to whatever IP he wants.  And this can penalize Google rankings very badly (because it considers the various domain names pointing to the same IP to  be duplicated contents and hence lowers the ranking of the site, even though it's legitimate).

Is there an easy to configure a standalone Tomcat using the equivalent of the following *mod_rewrite* for Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # redirect any request that came from a bad hostname
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>"
```

(I think the above is correct: basically I want to 301 (permanent redirect) anything that is **not** *domain.com* to *domain.com*)

Obviously it is easy to do under Apache but I'd like to know how to it when running Tomcat in standalone mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you are looking for the Tomcat Equivalent of Apache's Mod Rewrite then Tuckey's
[Url Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) will do this for you

This makes use of [ServletFilters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) to do this, so it will work in any Servlet container, not just Tomcat

There should be enough info in the [examples provided](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/guide.html) to help you